# ServiceNow listener

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

So preferably using GO or Python is there a way to listen to servicenow API so that whenever a ticket is assigned to my group, it can instantly trigger a local script? I have it set that some of our tasks in my group are completed with a local script, but there is nothing to trigger them. I tried using a websocket, but it redirected to https and some of the documentation seems to indicate that the ws protocol is not supported. Any thoughts?

Comment: I can only think about using AMB for this. Look some of the posts from community like [here](https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_article&sys_id=8952b2eadb7018d0414eeeb5ca96198c) or [here](https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=8da3601ddb11d49014d6fb2439961945)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a service now business rule to post to an api
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/quebec-application-development/page/script/business-rules/concept/c_BusinessRules.html